# C Programming - Does not Compute Values

Tags: c

Can someone tell me why this code does not compute the gross pay and the others? There is a problem in this code wherein it does not compute like the program is wanted to. Can someone help me pinpoint the errors?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
  char fname[20];
  char lname[20];
  char IDnumber[20];
  char Position;
  float Hoursworked,Grosspay,Tax,Netpay;

  printf(" ************iG Company************** \n\n");
  printf("Enter the employee's First Name:\n");
  scanf("%s", &fname);
  printf("Enter the employee's Last Name:\n");
  scanf("%s", &lname);
  printf("Enter IDnumber:\n");
  scanf("%s",&IDnumber);
  printf("<1>Manager <2>Supervisor heart>Employee <4>Office Boy/girl \n");
  printf("Enter Position:\n");
  scanf("%s", &Position);
  switch(Position)
  {
    case '1':
      printf("Rate per hour:P150.00 \n");
      printf("No. of hours worked:");
      scanf("%d", &Hoursworked);
      Grosspay = Hoursworked * 150;
      printf("Gross: \n", Grosspay);
      Tax = Grosspay * 0.1f;
      printf("TAX:\n", Tax);
      Netpay = Grosspay - Tax;
      printf("NET PAY: \n", Netpay);
      break;
    case '2':
      printf("Rate:P100.00 \n");
      printf("No. of hours worked:");
      scanf("%d", &Hoursworked);
      Grosspay = Hoursworked * 100;
      printf("Gross:\n", Grosspay);
      Tax = Grosspay * 0.1f;
      printf("TAX: \n", Tax);
      Netpay = Grosspay-Tax;
      printf("NET PAY: \n", Netpay);
      break;
    case '3':
      printf("Rate:P70.00 \n");
      printf("No. of hours worked:");
      scanf("%d", &Hoursworked);
      Grosspay = Hoursworked * 70;
      printf("Gross: \n", Grosspay);
      Tax = Grosspay * 0.1f;
      printf("TAX:\n", Tax);
      Netpay = Grosspay - Tax;
      printf("NET PAY: \n", Netpay);
      break;
    case '4':
      printf("Rate per hour:P50.00 \n");
      printf("No. of hours worked:");
      scanf("%d", &Hoursworked);
      Grosspay = Hoursworked * 50;
      printf("Gross:\n", Grosspay);
      Tax = Grosspay * 0.1f;
      printf("TAX:\n", Tax);
      Netpay = Grosspay - Tax;
      printf("NET PAY:\n", Netpay);
      break;
    default:
      printf("Invalid");
  }
  getch();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you indent your code?

Comment: What does it do ?  What is the difference between what you expect and what your program delivers ?

Comment: it does not compute the gross pay, net pay and the others when i compile it. it is just there with an empty value.

Comment: Try to reduce your code to a minimal example which still behaves unexpected. Limiting code size will make it easier for us to answer and it is more likely that you will find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program actually computes the value but does not print it.
Change,

```
scanf("%d",&Hoursworked);

Grosspay=Hoursworked*150;
printf("Gross: \n",Grosspay);
Tax=Grosspay*0.1f;
printf("TAX:\n",Tax);


Netpay=Grosspay-Tax;
printf("NET PAY: \n",Netpay);
```

to

```
scanf("%f",&Hoursworked); //Houseworked is declared float

Grosspay=Hoursworked*150;
printf("Gross: **%f**\n",Grosspay); //you have to specify what type to print
Tax=Grosspay*0.1f;
printf("TAX:**%f**\n",Tax);


Netpay=Grosspay-Tax;
printf("NET PAY: **%f**\n",Netpay);
```

change the full code accordingly and you should get the result..:)

Comment: +1 Happy hundred, @tausun! ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's computed but not printed, because you're missing `%f` in the format string in `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("Gross:\n",Grosspay);
```

You are missing a placeholder for the variable in that string. When you use printf to output variable values, the first string must include placeholders where the following variables are inserted.

```
printf("Gross: %f\n",Grosspay);
```

The %f will be replaced with the value of Grosspay.